# How can I create a log when a program is installed in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, logging

Is there a way to log when a program is installed on windows server 2008?

I look at my logs, at application logs, but dont see when I install something like for example WinSCP.

Answer (score 2):

Check in `%ProgramFiles%` for the folder creation date for your application. You will know when it was installed.

Comment: That's pretty smart. +1

Comment: Sorry I have made myself not clear enough, Is it possible to log when a program is installed? anyhow thx anyway

Comment: @nickbijmoer oh ok, I understand now. builtin I never tried it, but I would check folder auditing. Check there; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408940(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_step2 to create a folder auditing policy that target **Create** & in **%ProgramFiles%**